# How to add an "All" option to check all items in the DropDown

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

I have a multiselection DropDown like below :-

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server" Width="200px"  Skin="MetroTouch" AutoPostBack="true" 
                    DropDownAutoWidth="Enabled" CheckBoxes="true" />
```

Now I don't want to use `EnableCheckAllItemsCheckBox="true"` property, instead I want to add an `"All"` option at the top of the list and when my .aspx page loads this DropDown should show `"All"` option by default ( checking all the items in the DropDown by default. ) and when I do uncheck for `"All"` then it should uncheck all the items in my dropdown, thus allowing me to select only the desired items.

How to achieve this, could anyone please help, ThankYou !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done using `EnableCheckAllItemsCheckBox="true"` and `EmptyMessage="Select"` for my dropdown, that fitted my requirement anyway. Thanks !